# JS setInterval; I want to create a tag string inside

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clock

```
let interval = setInterval(() => {

    var date = new Date();
    var saat = date.getHours();
    var dakika = date.getMinutes();
    var saniye = date.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById("saat").innerHTML = saat + ": " + dakika + ": " + saniye;

}, 1000);
```

I want to create a `li` tag with hour value. Can you please help me?

Comment: What is the actual problem? The function's syntax is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new DOM element by using [createElement](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp) method. Please try the code-snippet below and see if it works for you.

```
let interval = setInterval(() => {
    var date = new Date();
    var saat = date.getHours();
    var dakika = date.getMinutes();
    var saniye = date.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById("saat").innerHTML = saat + ": " + dakika + ": " + saniye;

    const ul = document.createElement('ul');
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = saat;
    ul.appendChild(li);
}, 1000);
```

I've presumed few things here so please make sure to make suitable changes to the code-snippet for your use-case.